# How can I send notification emails from prase to my users

Tags: android-layout, parse-platform, android-studio-2.0

I want to send notification email from parse to my users but I have spent too much time in it. Alas! I can't find path. Please anybody guide me how can I do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending notification emails is not a service that is offered by Parse.  And given that in about 7 months, no services will be offered by Parse at all, this is a good time to start shifting to a different backend solution.

Comment: OK. Please give me suggestion which type of back end will be used for it?

Comment: You'll need to setup your own database and server to replace parse (or find an alternate MBaaS) and then from your server, you can use something like SendGrid to automate password reset emails.  This is not a trivial task - you should first focus on finding a different backend solution to replace Parse since it will be shut down in January 2017.